# How to create a dropdown menu in the nav bar

Tags: html, css

Hi I was ask to create the nav bar for my sch project and my nav bar is home...more information, I need to create a drop down menu at more information which contain 3 other pages but i have no idea how. Can someone please teach me.

Answer (score 0):

Use nested lists like `ul > li > ul > li` 
Here is an example i prepared for you http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOWexM

Answer (score 0):

[Sample 1](http://www.webcodegeeks.com/html5/html5-dropdown-menu-example-with-css3/)

[Sample 2](http://demo.ourtuts.com/menu/)

Here is a few samples of how to implement a dropdown in css and html , Use a < ul > and style the items to drop with relative position